# Integrate Power BI embedding in Xamarin Forms / how to display a Power BI report

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I need help with a problem, it is new to me, integrating PowerBI reports into a Xamarin application. What I have is the access token, and with that, along with the workspaceId and reportId, I am making a call to the PowerBI service.

```
    private async Task<string> ObtenerEmbedUrl(string accessToken)
    {
        string powerBIDatasetsApiUrl = $"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{workspaceId}/reports/{reportId}";


        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(powerBIDatasetsApiUrl);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var responseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseContent);
                string embedUrl = responseJson["embedUrl"].ToString();

                Debug.WriteLine($"EmbedUrl obtenido: {embedUrl}");

                return embedUrl;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error al obtener el EmbedUrl.");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

With this, I obtain the EmbedUrl and am displaying it directly in the WebView, which I've already seen won't work. What should I do to display the PowerBI report in a Xamarin view?

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        Debug.WriteLine("#########");
        Debug.WriteLine("# Start #");
        Debug.WriteLine("#########");

        string accessToken = await ObtenerTokenDeAcceso(); // Token de acceso
        string embedUrl = await ObtenerEmbedUrl(accessToken);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(embedUrl))
        {
            // Carga el informe en la WebView con el token de acceso
            powerBIWebView.Source = new UrlWebViewSource
            {
                Url = embedUrl
            };
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error al obtener el EmbedUrl.");
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("#########");
        Debug.WriteLine("#  End  #");
        Debug.WriteLine("#########");
    }
```

Do you have any ideas on how I should display the PowerBI report in Xamarin.Forms? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That's the wrong embedding workflow for that scenario.  You need to use the Javascript library in your web view, and generate an all the embedding parameters into a JWT to use in the browser.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/powerbi-implementation-planning-usage-scenario-embed-for-your-customers

The "embedUrl" for the report is for secure embedding, where the end user authenticates using their own AAD identity.